# Variable Accessible by All Methods Without Parameters?

Tags: java

Is it possible to have a "global" variable, i.e., "balance", which all methods can access without parameters?

Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args{
    makevariablehere
}
```

Could be called in another method:

```
public static int someMethod() {
    variable = newVariable;
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't have Global variables. You can declare a static field in some class and make it as visible as you'd like, but I discourage it.

Comment: I agree with Sotirios, but I'd have said "**Thank heaven,** Java doesn't have Global variables."... (Well, we have Singleton pattern instead, but thats a whole different story...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it as a static field on the class.  See the example below, which stores the number of args passed to the main method in a static field, so that it may be returned by the `getNumberOfArgs()` method.

```
public class MyClass {

  private static int argCount;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    argCount = args.length;
  }

  public static int getNumberOfArgs() {
    return argCount;
  }
}
```